# take some string with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

in Javascript i tried to read `window.location.search`. value of this variable could be something like `?ref=somestring&read=1` or `?read=1&ref=sometring` or just `?ref=somestring`.

how to extract only `ref=somestring` from the variable?

so far i tried the following regex:

```
ref.match(/ref=([^\&].*)\&/) // works when ?ref=somestring&read=1
ref.match(/ref=([^\&].*)\&/) // not working when only ?ref=somestring
ref.match(/ref=([^\&].*)\&?/) // works when ?ref=somestring
ref.match(/ref=([^\&].*)\&?/) // works but took all part if ?ref=somestring&read=1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
var m = (ref.match(/[?&](ref[^&]+)/) || ['', ''])[1];
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cE4pF4/1)

This regex firs matches: `?` or `&` followed by literal text `ref=` followed by `[^&]+` and groups `ref[^&]+` in group `#1`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ref.match(/(ref=[^\&]*)/) //for ref=somestring
```

or

```
ref.match(/ref=([^\&]*)/) //for somestring
```

[REGEX DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a41y9vqy/)